# What's a conventional or useful notation for "second-highest"?

Tags: notation

What would the conventional or an otherwise useful notation for the second-highest value of $v_i, i=1,\ldots,n$ be?

I use $v_{n-1:n}$, which I used in statistics, but that may not be quite intuitively graspable. $v_{(n-1)}$ seems like asking for trouble.

So perhaps I am missing an obvious candidate. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name for what you're after is [order statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

If you have a sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$ the conventional notation for the $i$th order statistic is $X_{(i)}$, so the second highest value in the sample would be $X_{(n-1)}$ as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks. Nothing along the lines of $v_{(n)}=\max_i v_i, v_{(n-1)}=\mathrm{blabla}_i v_i$?

Comment: I found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations) and there's nothing like $\mathrm{blabla}$ there. Done.